# Most efficient algorithm to generate a site map?

Tags: c, xml, algorithm, sitemap

..given an URL as input (C programming language). (Sitemap specifications from sitemap.org).

Comment: Could you be more specific about what you're asking about please? You want a strategy and an algorithm that categorizes links? You want an algorithm that scrapes links from HTML? You want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated in the comments by apphacker we don't really know what you're trying to do. If you are planning on just scraping links from a html website then I would recommend some sort of lexical scanner generator: like flex.

If you are getting a website url as input then you are going to need to use the some networking code to read the webpages. If you don't know anything about networking in C then I would recommend googling beej's guides and going from there.

If you are just getting a straight XML file as your tags suggest then once again I would recommend flex if you absolutely must use C. If you don't have to use C then I would recommend Perl or Python; they are probably better suited to the job.

Either way we need you to give us more information but I hope that helps for now.